# Access media/TV on a Windows Media Center PC from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, streaming, windows-media-center

Is it possible to access media/live or recorded TV on a PC running Win 7 shared via Windows Media Center from a Ubuntu machine (12.04)? I can access media stored to disk via the Workgroup shares but I imagine WMC is accessed differently.

To clarify: I'd like to stream media to the Ubuntu machine from WMC shares.

Is there another program that can grab a tuner feed and send it to the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Have you looked into VLC yet?

Comment: I have not actually - I'll check that out. I know it offers streaming functionality but from my experience with it, I wouldn't call it a solution. Large amount of color/image distortion/noise.